# Recieving JSON data from my PHP file to my Angular2 component

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular 2. I'm having a problem receiving JSON data from my PHP file to my angular2 component
getting error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`.

Why I can't get the `response_array` into the Angular 2 subscription data property?
 Please, someone, point me in the right direction.

addComponent:

```
logForm(value: any) {

    this.addPrayerService.addService(value);

}
```

addService:

```
addService(value){

    let params = new URLSearchParams();
            params.set('value', value.message);

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;  charset=utf-8' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.post(this._contactUrl, params.toString() , options)
                    .map(res =>  <string> res.json())
                    .subscribe(data => console.log(data));

}
```

add.php:

```
<?php 

header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
$response_array= array( 'status' => 'Success' );
echo json_encode($response_array);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

> JSON.parse(res) to decode the response value as json

Comment: and where do i put it  in the map function